# python 3.6 open mvs dataset

Tags: python-3.x, zos

I am trying to open a MVS dataset in z/OS python 3.6.1 using the following syntax:

```
f = open("//'my.dataset'", 'rb')
```

As I know, it works in Python 2.7.6. However, when I tried to do the similar code, it kept saying that `FileNotFoundError`. I have tried changing the data set name to `ebcdic`, but it still didn't work. Is there anyone who has experience on this and help?

Comment: Is this Rocket Software's python?

Comment: Yes, it is downloaded from Rocket Software.

Comment: I'd suggest asking there, then.

Comment: We had an issue on an older release of Python where stat() was issued against the filename prior to open() inside the Python runtime. In this case, your z/OS dataset name syntax isn't properly handled, and the result is that "FileNotFoundError". Apologies, but I forget exactly what release we found this in - perhaps this problem has reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

as a work around, you can make use of system command to copy the dataset in a temporary file.

```
    `    rc = os.system("cp " + "//'my.dataset'" + " " + "temp")
         with open("temp", 'r') as fin:
            print(fin.read())`
```

***rc*** will contain the return code of the command

to delete the file you can use

```
os.remove("temp")
```